# jQuery to loop through ASP.NET gridview asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

suppose i have gridview in my aspx page and gridivew has many rows and 3 columns. column are

select - checkbox, first name - textbox ,last name - textbox etc

i want to loop through gridview by jquery and read those textbox value from that row where check box is selected.

### gridview look like

```
<asp:GridView
    id="GridView1"
    DataSourceID="srcMovies"
    DataKeyNames="Id"
    Runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
```

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblslno" runat="server" />    
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" runat="server" />    
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLName" runat="server" />    
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

i got jquery code to read textbox value from each row if checkbox is selected...here is code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var sum = 0;
     $('#btn1').click(function () {
         $('#tr').each(function () {
             if ($(this).find('input:checkbox').attr("checked"))
                 sum += parseInt($(this).find('input:text').attr("value"));
         });
         window.alert(sum.toString());
     });
 });
</script>
```

my concern is how to read data from txtFName & txtLName textboxes and label lblslno on each row. can anyone drive toward right code. thanks

### i got a good solution....here it is

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-json.googlecode.com/files/jquery.json-2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var jsonData = new Array();
    $(".getJSON").click(function() {
        $.map($("table[id*=gvPurchaseOrderDetails] tr"), function(item, index) {
            if ($(item).find("input[type=text]").length>0) {
                jsonData[index] = new Object();
                jsonData[index].employeeid = $(item).find("input[type=text][id*=employeeid]").val();
                jsonData[index].employeename = $(item).find("input[type=text][id*=employeename]").val();
                jsonData[index].sex = $(item).find("select[id*=sex]").val();
                jsonData[index].graduate = $(item).find("input[type=checkbox][id*=graduate]").attr("checked");
            }
        });

        var jsonStringData = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
    });
});
```

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPurchaseOrderDetails" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="employeeid">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="employeeid" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="employeename">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="employeename" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="sex">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="sex" runat="server" ><asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Graduate">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="graduate" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<a class="getJSON" href="#">get json data</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridView is going to mangle the Ids of the textboxes. The easiest way would be to add a css class to the text boxes and then use that to find them:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" CssClass="FName" runat="server" />    
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLName" CssClass="LName" runat="server" />    
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**EDIT**: As suggested in the comments, they could then be found using the class selector:

```
$(this).find('.LName').val()
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it.  ID attributes need to be unique for each page so the GridView will append sequential numbers to them.  You should just add `CssClass="LName"`, `CssClass="FName"`, etc.

Comment: And your selector could be `$(this).find('.LName').val()`

Comment: @Terry - I modified the `CssClass`es in my example to match your comment.

Comment: can't we loop through like this - $("#calculate").click(function() {
                var result = 0;
                $("input:checkbox:checked[name$=check]").each(function() {
                    result += Math.round($(this).parents("tr").find("input:text[name$=amount]").val(), 4);
                });
                alert(result);
            });

Comment: var number_of_rows = $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> tr").size()

Comment: You don't have to add classes to your textboxes if you prefer you can use their order.. Something like `$('input:eq(0)' , this)` is the first one, `$('input:eq(1)' , this)` 2nd etc.. It depends if you want to add a lot of extra classes vs using an index and which you prefer.

Comment: @Thomas - I think it would more clear to simply add a css class to find your inputs rather than trying to have jquery parse a mangled name. But that can be personal preference.

Comment: @lucuma - That will work, but if the layout of the grid ever changes it could render the jQuery script incorrect.

Comment: @CAbbott Sure, and adding classes to every textbox in a large grid adds a lot of overhead to the document. It is give and take however you look. I wasn't suggesting using an index was better only an alternative.

Comment: @lucuma I don't see how adding a class to each element adds any noticeable overhead. Furthermore, aside from the grid layout change using `input:...` will traverse all input types.  Using classes you can specify which controls you actually want to look at.

Comment: @Terry Adding the words `class='fname'` and `class='lname'` to each row is adding overhead.  Using classes is fine, I'm not arguing against it, but it can  make the document size much larger especially when used in a repeating element. If it is so complex that readability is better than speed then great. If you are concerned about speed having those classes could make the document larger(think 100 rows updated via ajax) and getting elements by index is *probably* faster. Anyways, I was only commenting on a different valid way to achieve the same result.